# Angular2 - huge development JS size for a small project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack

I have a pretty basic `todos` project .
The project was first started as `angular-cli` basic template but becuase  `webpack.config.js` had many built in statement which I didn't need- I've managed to clean and yield basic working angular2 webpack config file :

```
module.exports = {

    entry: {
        "main": ["./src\\main.ts"],
        "polyfills": ["./src\\polyfills.ts"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        "publicPath": "/dist/"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            }
        ]
    },plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      __dirname
    )
]
};
```

*(I did however needer to install the two loaders , but that's irrelevant )*

- If I run `webpack` - I get  :

[image]

- If I run `webpack -p` - I get  :

[image]

- If I run `webpack -d` - I get  :

[image]

In development mode the file is Huge ( and takes longer to create  , which I understand , but it takes 10 seconds each time)

**Question**

Regularly I work with `webpack -d --watch` , but as you can see it takes longer (10 seconds each compile)

Is there any feature which I can enable/disable in order for the compilation to be faster  - while still working with `-d --watch`?

Comment: No bundling will take time, for me It takes around 3minutes every time I save.

Comment: @Aravind Then you should fix that :-) JK

Comment: No. I run a sequence of operations based on which my application will fail if I make any tslint error as well, so for saving time i will work on the bundle js itself if the fix is for small try. Else repeast steps

Comment: is the issue that the bundles are huge? or that the compilation time takes too long?

Comment: @pixelbits Hi;) I can understand why the size is big in dev mode(`-d`). But those 12 seconds are really annoying.  Generally - Is the file in dev mode is a normal size? and is there away to reduce the time ? so basically I'm after both of them. ( but if you ask for one  - it's the time to buiild)

Comment: Could you setup your development environment to not bundle - i.e. use SystemJS loader?

Comment: @pixelbits It it normal for the seed project of angular 2 cli - after `webpack -p` to be ~768 kb ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't use cli or webpack, but 768 kb does seem large for a production app bundle using AOT. Is it minified?

Comment: @pixelbits Yes it is , but not gzipeed.